# Integrals of velocity and time in infinitesimal time interval

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, calculus

I am reading Special Relativity for Beginners, by Jurgen Freund, and Chapter 12 is on Accelerated Motion. I am having a difficulty with a basic integral laid out in there.

The equation of the x-component of acceleration when converting from the primed frame to the unprimed frame (primed frame has only relative velocity $v$ to unprimed frame in x-direction) is given by

$$a_x = \frac{1}{ \gamma \left( 1+\frac{u'_xv}{c^2}\right)^3}a'_x $$

Consider a body accelerating along x-axis

If the primed frame is an instantenous reference frame which has the same instantaneous velocity $v$ as the accelerating body $u_x$ [i.e $ v = u_x$], then the body has instantaeous velocity 0 in the instantaneous, primed frame, while still having proper acceleration  $\alpha$

The acceleration in the primed frame, in terms of alpha, is given as

$$a' = (a'_x, 0, 0) = (\alpha, 0, 0) = const$$

But by the first equation, we see that this means its acceleration in the unprimed frame, is

$$a = (a_x, 0, 0) = (\frac{1}{\gamma^3}\alpha, 0, 0) $$

And focusing on the x, component,

$$a_x =  \frac{du_x}{dt} = \left(1 - \frac{u_x^2}{c^2}\right)^\frac{3}{2}\alpha $$

which implies

$$du_x = \left(1 - \frac{u_x^2}{c^2}\right)^\frac{3}{2}\alpha dt$$

The book then states that integrating both sides of the above equation, we obtain

$$\int_{0}^{u_x} \frac{du_x}{(c^2 - u_x^2)^\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{\alpha}{c^3}\int_{0}^{t}dt$$

I know that this must seem like such a silly question, but I am genuinely unable to see why we can make the integration on the right hand side from 0 to $t$, instead of from 0 to $u^x$. Why is that integral correct? Is it relying on some underlying rule of calculus, or on some fact about the motion of the body?

Comment: If you assume that the velocity of the primed frame in the unprimed frame is 0 at T=0 and u_x at T=t, then of course 0 and t will be the limits of integration when you integrate w.r.t. time. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks @FelisSuper ... Perhaps you mean intuitively? I am asking more for a reference to the mathematical theorem or premise that justifies that intuition ...

Comment: Then that is a question about the math, not the physics. But this makes sense mathematically too. As the integral is (loosely speaking) regarded as a "sum" of the integrand from some initial point (say x=a, where x is the variable you're integrating with respect to) to some final point x=b, then that is equivalent to "summing" from some f(a) to f(b) (where f(x) is some function) if the integrand is a function g(f(x)). For each value x_0 in the sum (which ranges from a to b), you get some value f(x_0) that is substituted into g, so f will range from f(a) to f(b) as x ranges from a to b.

Comment: So this can also be regarded as a sum with respect to f(x) from f(a) to f(b). In your example, x can be regarded as the time t, u_x is the function of t (so it is the function f(x), or equivalently, f(t)), and g(f(t))=g(u_x) is the integrand in the integral to the left in the last equation. So instead of integrating with respect to t (like you do on the R.H.S. of the last equation), you can integrate with respect to f(t)=u_x, due to my reasoning above.

Comment: Just adding your name @midawn98, so that you get a notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the limits as $u_f$ and $u_i$ on the left and $t_f$ and $t_i$ for the right... since you are integrating over $u$ and $t$, respectively.

Thinking about units would also be helpful.
 What should the units of the right-hand-side be?

How would you handle ordinary kinematics with constant acceleration $dv=a\ dt$?

Comment: So in the case of the ordinary kinematics equation, isn't that kind of different, since we dont have the left hand side as a function of u_x as above?

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question!

The limit on the right-hand side is from $0$ to $t$ because that is the interval of time we are considering (It is defined by the problem). In that interval of time, the speed changed from 0 to $u_{x}$, hence the limits on the left-hand side.

Good luck with these things!!

Comment: I see, so if I am understanding this correctly, we cannot take a smaller value as we would be leaving out some interval of time, and we cannot take a larger one because that would include a time interval which has not yet passed?